# KmsiLifetimeMins named parameter notfound

Tags: powershell, adfs

I have set up **ADFS** by watch YouTube, for **SSO** with **Java web application**. Whenever I browse with the URL https://hostname.domain.name/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx, ADFS asking the user to login every times when user open a browser.

I have went to through the article from Microsoft [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/adfs/set-adfsproperties) I have enabled the property of **EnableKmsi** to make user to login once and until the user wish to logout from the URL https://hostname.domain.name/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx. When I go through the article I have read about the property of **KmsiLifetimeMins**(in Minutes). This property is used to keep the user as signed in until the time out mentioned in this property.

Default value for this property is **1440 i.e.24 hours**. I tried to change this property value to **48 hours**, from PowerShell by use the following commands

```
Set-AdfsProperties -KmsiLifetimeMins:$2880

Set-AdfsProperties -KmsiLifetimeMins:2880
```

But when I try to run one of the above mentioned command I get the error

```
Set-AdfsProperties : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'KmsiLifetimeMins'.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-AdfsProperties -KmsiLifetimeMins:$10
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AdfsProperties], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.SetServiceProperties
   Command
```

I don't know why the error is raising am using **Windows Server 2012 R2** evaluation type of Datacenter version. Is am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why the error is raising am using **Windows Server 2012 R2** evaluation type of Datacenter version. Is am doing anything wrong?

KMSI is an ADFS 4.0 feature. You're currently working with ADFS 3.0

You'll need Windows Server 2016 for ADFS 4.0

Comment: Oh thanks for the update @Mathias. Is there any other property to change the keep me sing in time?

Comment: @BhuvaneshWaran No, you can't enable a feature that isn't there :-) You'll have to configure a longer session lifetime on the individual service (so on the Java Web app side)